# Fixed divs but relative margin like Facebook chat window

Tags: html, css

How to do fixed div's but with relative distances to one another? (like facebook chat windows).

But, the chat windows are one over the other (not a side by side :( ), so, how to do to make this? It's possible with CSS only?

```css
.chat_window {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 999;
}
.chat_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.chat_header span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='chat_window'>
  <div class='chat_header'>
    <span>One name...</span>
  </div>

  <div class='chat_body'>
    <span> a chat window</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='chat_window'>
  <div class='chat_header'>
    <span>Other name...</span>
  </div>

  <div class='chat_body'>
    <span> other chat window</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;**

You can't do that with `position: fixed;`, but you may use a single block with fixed position and keep your chat windows aligned there.

Another option is to use JavaScript, have a look at the article about [Facebook Style Chat Box Popup using JavaScript and CSS](http://qnimate.com/facebook-style-chat-box-popup-using-javascript-and-css/)

```css
.chat_area {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}
.chat_window {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 999;
}
.chat_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.chat_header span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat_area">
  <div class='chat_window'>
    <div class='chat_header'>
      <span>One name...</span>
    </div>

    <div class='chat_body'>
      <span> a chat window</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='chat_window'>
    <div class='chat_header'>
      <span>Other name...</span>
    </div>

    <div class='chat_body'>
      <span> other chat window</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any obvious ways of doing it purely with CSS. If it possible to add a parent `div` then I would recommend doing so. It's a simple solution whereby you give the parent container a fixed position and make the children float to the right. This should give you your desired effect:

```css
#chat_parent{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.chat_window
{
  float:right;
  width: 280px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 999;
}

.chat_header
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.chat_header span
{
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat_parent">
  <div class='chat_window'>
    <div class='chat_header'>
      <span>One name...</span>
    </div>
    <div class='chat_body'>
      <span> a chat window</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='chat_window'>
    <div class='chat_header'>
      <span>Other name...</span>
    </div>
    <div class='chat_body'>
      <span> other chat window</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll update/delete my answer if I find a CSS only solution.